# How to clean JTextPanes/JEditorPanes html content to string in Java?

Tags: java, html, string, jtextpane

I try to get pretty (cleaned) text content from JTextPane. Here is example code from `JTextPane`:

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane ();
textPane.setContentType ("text/html");
textPane.setText ("This <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.");
String text = textPane.getText ();
System.out.println (text);
```

Text look like this in `JTexPane`:

> This **is** a **test**.

I get this kind of print to console:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    This <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.
  </body>
</html>
```

I've used `substring()` and/or `replace()` code, but it is uncomfortable to use:

```
String text = textPane.getText ().replace ("<html> ... <body>\n    , "");
```

Is there any simple function to remove all other tags than `<b>` tags (content) from string?

Sometimes `JTextPane` add `<p>` tags around content so I want to get rid of them also.

Like this:

```
<html>
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      hdfhdfgh
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to get only text content with tags:

```
This <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I subclassed [`HTMLWriter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLWriter.html) and overrode `startTag` and `endTag` to skip all tags outside of `<body>`.

I did not test much, it seems to work ok. One drawback is that the output string has quite a lot of whitespace. Getting rid of that shouldn't be too hard.

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
        textPane.setContentType("text/html");
        textPane.setText("<p>This</p> <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.");

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        HTMLDocument doc = (HTMLDocument) textPane.getStyledDocument();

        HTMLWriter htmlWriter = new OnlyBodyHTMLWriter(writer, doc);
        htmlWriter.write();

        System.out.println(writer.toString());
    }

    private static class OnlyBodyHTMLWriter extends HTMLWriter {

        public OnlyBodyHTMLWriter(Writer w, HTMLDocument doc) {
            super(w, doc);
        }

        private boolean inBody = false;

        private boolean isBody(Element elem) {
            // copied from HTMLWriter.startTag()
            AttributeSet attr = elem.getAttributes();
            Object nameAttribute = attr
                    .getAttribute(StyleConstants.NameAttribute);
            HTML.Tag name = null;
            if (nameAttribute instanceof HTML.Tag) {
                name = (HTML.Tag) nameAttribute;
            }
            return name == HTML.Tag.BODY;
        }

        @Override
        protected void startTag(Element elem) throws IOException,
                BadLocationException {
            if (inBody) {
                super.startTag(elem);
            }
            if (isBody(elem)) {
                inBody = true;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void endTag(Element elem) throws IOException {
            if (isBody(elem)) {
                inBody = false;
            }
            if (inBody) {
                super.endTag(elem);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This working well, thanks. Anyway sometimes textPane add <p> -tags around the content so I want also get rid of them. Like this kind content:

    <p style="margin-top: 0">
      This <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.
    </p>

To:

This <b>is</b> a <b>test</b>.

I try to solve this problem but I'm very thankful for help and solution.

Comment: I have solved problem. :-) I changed `return name == HTML.Tag.BODY;` to `return name == HTML.Tag.P;` and tested many times to check if that works. Even there isn't `<p>` -tags it worked like a charm. I also add `writer.toString().trim()` -method so I get pretty output. :-D Extreme big thanks to you. :-D

Answer (score 1):

I find solution to this problem by using substring and replace -methods:

```
// Get textPane content to string
String text = textPane.getText();

// Then I take substring to remove tags (html, head, body)
text = text.substring(44, text.length() - 19);

// Sometimes program sets <p style="margin-top: 0"> and </p> -tags so I remove them
// This isn't necessary to use.
text = text.replace("<p style=\"margin-top: 0\">\n      ", "").replace("\n    </p>", ""));

// This is for convert possible escape characters example &amp; -> &
text = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(text);
```

There is link to StringEscapeUtils -libraries which convert escape characters back to normal view. Thanks to Ozhan Duz for the suggestion.

([commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html) - [download](http://commons.apache.org/lang/download_lang.cgi))

Answer (score 1):

You could use the HTML parser that the JEditorPane uses itself, `HTMLEditorKit.ParserDelegator`.

See [this example](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/bookmarks/), and the [API docs.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/parser/ParserDelegator.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
String text = textPane.getDocument.getText (0,textPane.getText().length());
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works please? So you're saying that the Document's text is what the OP wanted here, including the tags? Why use the length from getText() not getDocument().getLength() ?